# Hilt in feature modules

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger-hilt, dynamic-feature-module

I added a dynamic feature module to the android project. I know that hilt does not support this type of modules. I found a workaround for this problem in google documentation.

[Hilt in feature modules](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-multi-module)

I have a project structure as below

- App - main module with application activity
- commons

  - utils - module with common functionalities for all android modules

    - database - includes DatabaseModule (hilt)
    - network - includes http client and NetworkModule (hilt)
    - injection - includes Mapbox Module Dependencies class
- core
- features

  - mapboxFeature - includes MapboxComponent and MapBoxModule

```
@Component(
    dependencies = [MapboxModuleDependencies::class],
    modules = [MapboxModule::class]
)
interface MapboxComponent {

    fun inject(fragment: MapboxMapFragment)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        fun context(@BindsInstance context: Context): Builder
        fun appDependencies(mapboxModuleDependencies: MapboxModuleDependencies): Builder
        fun build(): MapboxComponent
    }
}
```

```
@Module
class MapboxModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideGetMapTaskUseCase(repository: MapTaskRepository): GetMapTasksUseCase = GetMapTasksUseCase(repository)

    @Provides
    fun provideMapTaskRepository(dataSource: MapTaskDbDataSource): MapTaskRepository = MapTaskRepositoryImpl(dataSource)

    @Provides
    fun provideMapTaskDbDataSource(dbRepository: TaskDbRepository): MapTaskDbDataSource = MapTaskDbDataSourceImpl(dbRepository)
}
```

```
@EntryPoint
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
interface MapboxModuleDependencies {

    fun provideDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): AppDatabase

    fun provideTaskDao(appDatabase: AppDatabase): TaskDao

    fun provideTaskDbRepository(dao: TaskDao): TaskDbRepository
}
```

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object DatabaseModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context) = Room.databaseBuilder(
        context,
        AppDatabase::class.java,
        DatabaseConstants.databaseName
    ).allowMainThreadQueries().build()

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideTaskDao(appDatabase: AppDatabase) = appDatabase.taskDao()

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideTaskDbRepository(dao: TaskDao): TaskDbRepository = TaskDbRepositoryImpl(dao)

...
```

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        fun setDaggerMapboxComponent() {
            DaggerMapboxComponent.builder()
                .context(requireContext())
                .appDependencies(
                    EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(
                        requireContext(),
                        MapboxModuleDependencies::class.java
                    )
                )
                .build()
                .inject(this)
        }
...
```

when i run a project it gets logs like this:

```
> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin
C:\Users\piotrro\Desktop\wfm-mobile\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\com\apator\wfm\App_HiltComponents.java:173: error: [com.apator.utils.injection.MapboxModuleDependencies.provideDatabase(android.content.Context)] Members injection methods may only return the injected type or void.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements MapboxModuleDependencies,
                         ^C:\Users\piotrro\Desktop\wfm-mobile\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\com\apator\wfm\App_HiltComponents.java:173: error: [com.apator.utils.injection.MapboxModuleDependencies.provideTaskDao(com.apator.database.AppDatabase)] Members injection methods may only return the injected type or void.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements MapboxModuleDependencies,
                         ^C:\Users\piotrro\Desktop\wfm-mobile\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\com\apator\wfm\App_HiltComponents.java:173: error: [com.apator.utils.injection.MapboxModuleDependencies.provideTaskDbRepository(com.apator.utils.database.data.dao.TaskDao)] Members injection methods may only return the injected type or void.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements MapboxModuleDependencies,
                         ^error: Cannot inject members into qualified types
> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: where does DaggerMapboxComponent class come from ?

Comment: DaggerMapboxComponent is an autogenerated class based on the MapboxComponet interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `MapboxModuleDependencies` you should only define `TaskDbRepository` like this:

```
@EntryPoint
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
interface MapboxModuleDependencies {

    fun provideTaskDbRepository(): TaskDbRepository
}
```